# Таблица либо список с градацией цвета с помощью after и before

Tags: html, css

Возникли проблемы с созданием двух списков, как в макете. Знаю, что необходимо использовать `before` и `after`,　а дальше задавать `opacity` фону, однако, к какому бы тегу (будь то `li`, либо `p`) я не задавал пост-элемент, нигде  не получается нужный результат. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблицей вряд ли получится добиться разных высот строк, еще с учётом того, что должны быть параллельны соседней колонке, так что, скорее всего, делать нужно двумя списками, однако, так и не смог реализовать качественно, плюс эти смайлики...

Вместо маркеров использовать смайлик, или выключить маркировку и ставить картинками? В общем, либо у меня руки кривые, либо да. Вот код:

```css
.solve-list {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.solve-list_left {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
}

.solve-list_left li {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 8px;
}

.solve-list_left li::before {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  opacity: 0, 6;
  width: 30px;
}

.solve-list_lef`введите сюда код`t p {
  float: left;
}

.solve-list_right p {
  float: right;
}

.solve-list_right {
  float: right;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.solve-list_right li {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #01983b;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="solve-list">
  <div class="solve-list_left">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <p>Потери тепла</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Проникновение шума</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Грибок, сырость</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Выделение вредных веществ</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Расточительность</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Пожароопасность</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="solve-list_right">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <p>Высокая теплоизоляция, эффективность в суровых погодный условиях.</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Индекс снижения приведенного уровня ударного шума - 25 ДБ.</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Гидроизоляционние свойства. Низкое влагопоглощение - 0,1%</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Благодаря Радикальной полимеризации стирола PENBOARD не токсичен, биологически нейтрален, отвечает высоким экологическим стандартам.</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>В масштабах государства - снижение энергоемкости производства и экономия традиционных ресурсов, в масштабах каждого отдельного дома - сбережение тепла и экологии помещений, снижение трат на отопление.</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Пожаробезопасность - Г1. PENBOARD не поддерживает горение после прекращения контакта с открытым огнем.</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>`
```

Answer (score 2):

Различные цвета можно задать градиентом. А вот растягивание блоков в ряду проще добиться `flexbox`-ом. При этом я чередовал красные и зелёные блоки. Смайлы поставил из `FontAwesome`

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
  margin:0;
}
ul{
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:space-between;
  color:#fff;
}
li{
  flex:0 1 auto;
  padding:5px 20px;
  margin:0 0 10px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:baseline;
}
li:before{
  font-family:fontAwesome;
  font-size:150%;
  margin:0 10px 0 0;
}
li:nth-child(2n+1){
  background:linear-gradient(to right,rgba(255,0,0,.3) 20px,rgba(255,0,0,.6) 20px,rgba(255,0,0,.6) 40px,#f00 40px);
  padding-left:45px;
  width:calc(40% - 5px);
}
li:nth-child(2n+1):before{
  content:'\f11a';
}
li:nth-child(2n){
  background:linear-gradient(to left,rgba(0,255,0,.3) 20px,rgba(0,255,0,.6) 20px,rgba(0,255,0,.6) 40px,#0f0 40px);
  padding-right:45px;
  width:calc(60% - 5px);
}
li:nth-child(2n):before{
  content:'\f118';
}
table{
  width:100%;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  color:#fff;
}
td{
  padding:5px 20px;
  border:10px solid #fff;
  vertical-align:top;
}

td:first-child{
  padding-left:45px;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,rgba(255,0,0,.3) 20px,rgba(255,0,0,.6) 20px,rgba(255,0,0,.6) 40px,#f00 40px);
  border-left:none;
  width:40%;
}
td:last-child{
  padding-right:45px;
  background:linear-gradient(to left,rgba(0,255,0,.3) 20px,rgba(0,255,0,.6) 20px,rgba(0,255,0,.6) 40px,#0f0 40px);
  border-right:none;
  width:60%;
}
td span{
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  padding:6px 0 0 30px;
}
td span:before{
  font-family:fontAwesome;
  font-size:150%;
  display:inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  
}
td:last-child span:before{
  content:'\f118';
}
td:first-child span:before{
  content:'\f11a';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h2>Вариант со списком на flex</h2>
<ul>
 <li>Потери тепла</li>
 <li>Высокая теплоизоляция, эффективность в суровых погодный условиях.</li>
 <li>Проникновение шума</li>
 <li>Индекс снижения приведенного уровня ударного шума - 25 ДБ.</li>
</ul>
<h2>Вариант с таблицей</h2>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span>Потери тепла</span></td>
      <td><span>Высокая теплоизоляция, эффективность в суровых погодный условиях.</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>Пожароопасность</span></td>
      <td><span>Пожаробезопасность - Г1. PENBOARD не поддерживает горение после прекращения контакта с открытым огнем.</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам больше за ответ! Однако (я забыл упомянуть), необходимо сделать это без использования flex'ов, в этом самая большая, пожалуй, проблема. Однако, всё равно спасибо большое!

Comment: В таком случае только таблица, либо имитация таблицы (`display:table`). А почему без флексов?

Comment: Я бы сам с радостью использовал флексы, но таково требование заказчика - чистый css (без бутстрапа, без флексов).

Comment: `flex` это стандарт `css3` поддерживающийся начиная с IE10. С чего бы это вдруг не "чистый" `css`? Если нужна поддержка IE9 - мой ответ с градиентами и таблицей также не подходит.